# Nuget package restore path for .NET core dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, visual-studio-2015, .net-core-rc2

I've created a .NET core console application on Visual Studio(VS) 2015 Community edition Update 3. I've installed .NET core 1.0.1 Preview 2 Visual Studio 2015 tools.

I know for one thing that while running the .NET Core application for the first time, Visual Studio restores all the .NET Core nuget packages and dependencies in some location on local computer. It is certainly not the root directory of my project as I can observe it myself.

Can anyone help me with the exact path where I can see all the .NET core nuget packages getting downloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find all of the common .NET Core packages in `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared`.

Comment: Do you know about the other path that Bond_009 is suggesting? Running that command shows *C:\Users\myUserName\.nuget\packages\* path and I see lot of nuget packages related to .Net core getting downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Use this cmd to find the path: `dotnet nuget locals global-packages -l`

Comment: Ohh! Did I accept the wrong answer? Then, I believe `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared` is the primary install path whenever we install the .Net core SDK for the first time. Is it?